# Gitlab 8.0+ Email Issues

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

1. I used AWS to set a gitlab web-server. As known that AWS use elastic IP and domain to guarantee the consistency between WAN IP and LAN IP. When I set up my gitlab server, the domain is (for example) "a.com", then I change the AWS's domain name as "b.com". When I try to create a new account, gitlab sent me an email for confirmation. However, the link provided by gitlab is "a.com/confirmation/****", not the right one: "b.com/confirmation/***". So I still can't register now.
2. Gitlab sent me multiple emails which let me get bored with it. This is due to some unknown bugs or that I didn't confirm the registration yet.

Comment: Now, I have already finish the confirmation. But Gitlab still send me many same confirmation emails.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for question 1:

```
vi /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
```

and

modify the external_url as:

```
external_url 'http://yourdomain.com'
```

But I am still confused by the question 2.